# WPF DataGrid CancelEdit from within DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls

I'm stuck on what seems to be a basic DataGridTemplateColumn question.

I have created a WPF DataGrid **(sample code below)** with a DataGridTemplateColumn. Inside the DataGridTemplateColumn, I have created a UserControl for the CellEditingTemplate. Within this UserControl, I have a button (and/or want to monitor a keypress, etc) that I want to use to Cancel (or Commit) the changes to the datagrid cell.

**How do I go about notifying the DataGrid to CancelEdit from within the UserControl?**

```
<DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                        <Button Content="Cancel!">
                            <!--
                                How to make this Button Cancel Editing?
                                Click="Cancel"
                                Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
                            -->
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it is to give the grid a name (theGrid), add a click handler to the button like this...

```
<Button Content="Cancel!" Click="Button_Click">
```

...and then cancel editing in the handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    theGrid.CancelEdit();
}
```

The "correct" way to do it is to create a view model with a command handler, bind the button's Command property to it and then use an attached behavior that watches an event in your view model and triggers the cancel when it fires.